# Filtering nested value in JSON array

Tags: javascript

I have the following JSON and would like to filter on the companyName attribute. What is the best way to do this? The code has to check the companyNames for all character objects.

```json
{
  "updated_at": 1598015417,
  "characters": [{
      "character": "A",
      "companies": [{
          "companyId": 133,
          "companyName": "AB Company"
        },
        {
          "companyId": 764,
          "companyName": "A Company"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "character": "B",
      "companies": [{
          "companyId": 804,
          "companyName": "AB Company"
        },
        {
          "companyId": 472,
          "companyName": "B Company"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

The desired output when I search for "AB". It has to return the companies which are included in the search string.

```json
{
  "updated_at": 1598015417,
  "characters": [{
      "character": "A",
      "companies": [{
          "companyId": 133,
          "companyName": "AB Company"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "character": "B",
      "companies": [{
          "companyId": 804,
          "companyName": "AB Company"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: How are you filtering? What is the desired output?

Comment: @Mr.Polywhirl I've updated the question to make it more clear

Answer (score 2):

You will need to map accordingly:

```js
const data = {
  "updated_at": 1598015417,
  "characters": [{
    "character": "A",
    "companies": [
      { "companyId": 133, "companyName": "AB Company" },
      { "companyId": 764, "companyName": "A Company" }
    ]
  }, {
    "character": "B",
    "companies": [
      { "companyId": 804, "companyName": "AB Company" },
      { "companyId": 472, "companyName": "B Company"  }
    ]
  }]
};

const filterCompanies = ({ characters, ...data }, fnOrName) => ({
  ...data,
  characters: characters.map(({ companies, ...character }) => ({
    ...character,
    companies: companies.filter(typeof fnOrName === 'function' ?
      fnOrName : ({ companyName }) => companyName === fnOrName)
  }))
});

const filteredCompanies = filterCompanies(data,
  ({ companyName }) => companyName === 'AB Company'); // More robust
    
console.log(filteredCompanies);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { top: 0; max-height: 100% !important; }
```

Alternatively, you could simply call:

```js
const filteredCompanies = filterCompanies(data, 'AB Company');
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an iterative solution using [object-scan](https://github.com/blackflux/object-scan#readme)

```js
// const objectScan = require('object-scan');

const data = { updated_at: 1598015417, characters: [{ character: 'A', companies: [{ companyId: 133, companyName: 'AB Company' }, { companyId: 764, companyName: 'A Company' }] }, { character: 'B', companies: [{ companyId: 804, companyName: 'AB Company' }, { companyId: 472, companyName: 'B Company' }] }] };

const prune = objectScan(['characters[*].companies[*].companyName'], {
  rtn: 'count',
  filterFn: ({ gparent, gproperty, value, context }) => {
    if (value.includes(context)) {
      return true;
    }
    gparent.splice(gproperty, 1);
    return false;
  }
});

console.log(prune(data, 'AB')); // how many companies remain
// => 2

console.log(data);
// => { updated_at: 1598015417, characters: [ { character: 'A', companies: [ { companyId: 133, companyName: 'AB Company' } ] }, { character: 'B', companies: [ { companyId: 804, companyName: 'AB Company' } ] } ] }
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

```html
<script src="https://bundle.run/object-scan@15.0.0"></script>
```

*Disclaimer*: I'm the author of [object-scan](https://www.npmjs.com/package/object-scan)